# QueryBasedValueHolder cannot be cast to UnitOfWorkValueHolder JPA

Tags: java, jpa

i am stucked with it , I try to persist a entity (Cab) and a child (inventory).

```
public void updatePriceByType(Cab cab) { 

  try { 
    for(Inventory inventory : cab.getInventories()){
      inventory.setCab(cab); 
      em.persist(em.merge(inventory));
    } 
    em.persist(em.merge(cab)); 
  } 
  finally {
    if (null != em) { 
      em.close(); 
    } 
  } 
}
```

Getting exception as shown below:

```
Caused by: javax.persistence.RollbackException: java.lang.ClassCastException: org.eclipse.persistence.internal.indirection.QueryBasedValueHolder cannot be cast to org.eclipse.persistence.internal.indirection.UnitOfWorkValueHolder
at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.transaction.EntityTransactionImpl.commitInternal(EntityTransactionImpl.java:102)
at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.transaction.EntityTransactionImpl.commit(EntityTransactionImpl.java:63)
at org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager.doCommit(JpaTransactionManager.java:512)
... 44 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: org.eclipse.persistence.internal.indirection.QueryBasedValueHolder cannot be cast to org.eclipse.persistence.internal.indirection.UnitOfWorkValueHolder
at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.indirection.TransparentIndirectionPolicy.buildBackupClone(TransparentIndirectionPolicy.java:92)
at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.indirection.TransparentIndirectionPolicy.backupCloneAttribute(TransparentIndirectionPolicy.java:78)
at org.eclipse.persistence.mappings.ForeignReferenceMapping.buildBackupClone(ForeignReferenceMapping.java:225)
at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.descriptors.ObjectBuilder.buildBackupClone(ObjectBuilder.java:498)
at org.eclipse.persistence.descriptors.changetracking.DeferredChangeDetectionPolicy.buildBackupClone(DeferredChangeDetectionPolicy.java:219)
at org.eclipse.persistence.descriptors.changetracking.DeferredChangeDetectionPolicy.revertChanges(DeferredChangeDetectionPolicy.java:283)
at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.UnitOfWorkImpl.resumeUnitOfWork(UnitOfWorkImpl.java:5248)
at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.UnitOfWorkImpl.synchronizeAndResume(UnitOfWorkImpl.java:5197)
at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.RepeatableWriteUnitOfWork.synchronizeAndResume(RepeatableWriteUnitOfWork.java:548)
at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.UnitOfWorkImpl.commitAndResume(UnitOfWorkImpl.java:1154)
at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.transaction.EntityTransactionImpl.commitInternal(EntityTransactionImpl.java:84)
```

Comment: my crystal ball says there is an error in the line 69 :) No, seroiusly, please post the code that throws the Exception and the relevant parts of the entites

Comment: public void updatePriceByType(Cab cab) {
  try {
   for(Inventory inventory :             cab.getInventories()){
    inventory.setCab(cab);
    em.persist(em.merge(inventory));
   }
   em.persist(em.merge(cab));
  } finally {
   if (null != em) {
    em.close();
   }
  }
  
 }

Comment: In above method it throws Exception

Comment: Hi kostja , can you please explain the situation in which this casting Exception may be thrown? Thanks

Comment: I am not sure what causes the exception. I have noticed a different issue in the code though - calling `merge` wiht a new entity will also persist it (and return the managed copy). As the returned copy is already managed, there is no need to pass it to `persist`. Simply remove the persist calls around the merge calls. Depending on the cascading settings in your entities you would not need to do the merging manually, so please post the relevant parts of your entites (with the mapped attributes and annotations but without methods) - this could help.

Comment: And by post, I mean add it to the question, not to the comments and format it ;)

Answer (score 0):

Call persist() on the result on merge() makes no sense, as merge() will persist or update the object.
Where does the cab object come from originally that you need to call merge?  Was it read in another EntityManager/transaction or serialized?

The error should not be occurring, so you may want to log a bug on it.  Ensure you try the latest version first.
Also check that you are not using property access, and have side affects in your get/set methods.